# How to run windows cmd command "query session" in processbuilder in Java?

Tags: java, cmd, processbuilder

This is what I am trying

`ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe", "/c", "\"query && session\"");`

but I get the error:

```
'query' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

What I am doing wrong here?

Comment: What information do you need from `query session`? Maybe there are other ways to get them.

Answer (score 3):

The reason is you run a 32 bit Java VM on a 64 bit Windows. In that case the `%SystemRoot%\syswow64\cmd.exe` will be executed instead of `%SystemRoot%\system32\cmd.exe`.

Small example

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    for (String s : Arrays.asList("java.vm.name", "sun.arch.data.model")) {
        System.out.printf("%s=%s%n", s, System.getProperty(s));
    }
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe", "/c", "query session");
    pb.redirectOutput(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.INHERIT);
    pb.redirectError(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.INHERIT);
    pb.start();
}
```

output with a 32 bit JVM on 64 bit Windows

```
java.vm.name=Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM
sun.arch.data.model=32
'query' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

output with a 64 bit JVM on 64 bit Windows

```
java.vm.name=Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
sun.arch.data.model=64
 SESSIONNAME       USERNAME                 ID  STATE   TYPE        DEVICE
 services                                    0  Disc
>console           .....                     1  Active
```

**edit**

`%SystemRoot%\syswow64\cmd.exe` doesn't know the query command.

```
C:\Windows\SysWOW64>cmd
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Windows\SysWOW64>query
'query' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

`%SystemRoot%\system32\cmd.exe` know the query command.

```
C:\Windows\System32>cmd
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Windows\System32>query
Invalid parameter(s)
QUERY { PROCESS | SESSION | TERMSERVER | USER }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for making me think in this direction. Let me rectify my setup.

Comment: I am explicitly mentioning to open the cmd.exe from System32 as shown below:                                                                                         ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe", "/c", "\"query && session\"");                                                                                                                          still same error. :(

Comment: I need to force JVM to run C:\Windows\System32>cmd instead of C:\Windows\SysWOW64>cmd. How do i do it?

Comment: Use a 64bit JVM. Otherwise I there is no way. You can try it manually: 1) run: C:\Windows\SysWOW64, 2) start inside C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe, 3) query session. You will see that this isn't working.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all the support. :) much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

try to do it interactively... does this work?

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe");
pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
Process p = pb.start();
PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(p.getOutputStream());
writer.println("/c \"query && session\"");
```

Comment: thanks for your response.  I did try    new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe", "cmd.exe /c", "\"query && session\""); But it did not work. :(

Comment: can you wrap it up like that:

String[] cmd = new String[]{"cmd.exe", "/C", "START", "query", "session"};
ProcessBuilder pbs = new ProcessBuilder(cmd);
pbs.start();